# How to use npm package in browser after import in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have an npm module installed and can't figure it out how to use it in the browser after importing it.

First I installed the npm module by (just an example dummy module):

`npm install sample-module`

In my `package.json` I have added then:

`"type": "module"`

My `server.js` on Node looks like this:

```js
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

app.use('/assets', express.static('assets'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname) + '/views/index.html');
});

app.listen(PORT, _ => {
    console.log(`App deployed at Port ${PORT}`);
});
```

In my index.html (from /views/) I am referencing to this JS file, which is used in the browser:

`<script type="module" src="./assets/script.js"></script>`

And this `script.js` uses following:

```
import {one, two} from 'sample-module'
```

When I load the page in the browser I am then getting:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "sample-module". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Trying to update the import statement to `./sample-module` or even `../node_modules/sample-module` does not work.

So my question is: How to load a module installed by npm and loaded by the import statement on the browser?

What I have tried is to remove the `"type": "module"` from `package.json` and then update all import-statements to use `require()` and then used browserify to generate a `bundle.js` file, which I again referenced then in my `index.html`. That worked! But using the same setup with the import-statement doesn't worked. So how to achieve the same result with the import-statement?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i am new at nodjs but if you try to create server using node.js i think

npm `init --y` will help to simply generate an empty npm project and that will help you to avoid a lot of errors

then make sure that package name is correct

and try to use require rather than  import

e.x

```
let express = require('express');
let {one , two} = require('sample-module');
```

Comment: I already was able to solve it with require(), but I am looking for a way to get this work with import.

Answer (score 0):

After trying different approaches I came to an solution I want to share.

From the script.js file I used in the browser I moved following line in server.js in Node:

`import {one, two} from 'sample-module'`

In my script.js, which is used in the browser I am then calling corresponding imported functions. Then I used browserify to build a bundle.js with command:

`browserify script.js -o bundle.js`

In the index.html I then referenced to the new bundle.js file. That way I was able to use the npm module which was imported by the import-statement in the browser.